show that, the function f is injective
Consider $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined as:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x &: x \text{ irrational} \\
x + \sqrt{2} &: x \text{ rational}
\end{cases}
$$
I need to show that, $f$ is injective.
My attempt:
Case(i): If $x, y\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) =f(y)$ then by definition of $f$ we have $x+\sqrt{2}=y+\sqrt{2}$ which implies $x=y$
Case(ii): If $x, y\in\mathbb{Q}^c$ & $f(x) =f(y)$ then by definition of $f$ we have $x=y$
But to show that, $f$ is injective, we must consider one more case
case(iii) if one of $x$ & $y$ is rational & other is irrational. Say $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ & $y\in\mathbb{Q}^c$. In this case, $f(x) =f(y)$ imply $x+\sqrt{2}=y$. But in this case, we didn't get $x=y$? (Or I am missing something?)
Please help.

You'll need that the domain is $[0, 1]$.

@Martin So, $f$ is not injective? My bad Luck. I need to construct a function $f$, which is injective & whose range is contained in $\mathbb{Q}^c$. Sir, please can you help...

It is injective.

@MartinR sir, it is already $[0, 1]$

@AdamRubinson sir, but in case (iii) we didn't get $x=y$?

@GeneralMathematics: Is it possible that $x+\sqrt 2 = y$ if both $x, y$ are in the range $[0, 1]$?

This function is not injective. For $x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, $f(x)=x+\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. So, $f(x+\sqrt{2})=x+\sqrt{2}$ by definition of $f$. Thus, $f$ is not injective.

@SilvioM If $x\in[0,1]$, then $x+\sqrt2\notin[0,1]$, and therefore $f(x+\sqrt2)$ is undefined.

@MartinR sir, $x+\sqrt{2}=y$ then $|x-y|=\sqrt{2}$ is I am on correct track? If yes, please help me further

If $p$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then if $f(p)=f(y)$ then $f$ is NOT injective (as $p\ne y$) so this part of the proof must be a proof by contradiction.  $f(p) = p+\sqrt 2$ and $f(y) = y$ so if $f(p)=f(y)$ then $p+\sqrt 2= y$ and $p = y-\sqrt 2$.  Why is that a contradiction.  It's isn't a contradiction because $y-\sqrt 2$ can't be rational (it can) but note that $y\in [0,1]$ so .... where is $p=y-\sqrt 2$.

"x+2–√=y then |x−y|=2–√ " no need for absolute values.

Don't overthink it.   If $y$ is irrational than $f(y) = y$ and $f(y)=y \in [0,1]$.  If $x$ is rational then $f(x) = x+\sqrt 2$.  $x \in [0,1]$ so $f(x)=x+\sqrt 2 \in [\sqrt 2, 1+\sqrt 2]$.  So $f(y)= y \le 1 < \sqrt 2 \le x+\sqrt 2 = f(x)$.  So $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

ALTERNATIVELY:  If $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $x\in [0,1]$ then $0 \le x \le 1$ and $\sqrt 2 \le x +\sqrt 2 = f(x) \le 1 + \sqrt 2$.  If $y \not \in \mathbb Q$ and $y \in [0,1]$ then $0 \le y = f(y) \le 1$.  Thus $f(x) = f(y)$ is impossible... there are two ways to prove injectivity.  One is: $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$.  The other is the contrapositive: $x\ne y \implies f(x) \ne f(y)$.

Thank you everyone, for clearing by doubts. I don't understand, I added details of my attempt, posted in latex form & engage in learning. But, still I get negative votes. Is something wrong? This is happening every time.

"I don't understand, I added details of my attempt, posted in latex form & engage in learning. But, still I get negative votes. Is something wrong? This is happening every time."  The world is full of jerks.  And reputation points do not matter.  Don't worry about it. (I upvoted to counter FWIW)


f one of x & y is rational & other is irrational. Say x∈Q & y∈Qc. In this case, f(x)=f(y) imply x+2–√=y. But in this case, we didn't get x=y? (Or I am missing something?)

As $x\ne y$ we can't get $x=y$.  We must do a proof by contradiction to get a contradiction.
Why is $x+\sqrt 2 = y$ a contradiction?
We assumed that $f(x) = f(y)$. This is assuming that $f(x), f(y)$ are both  defined and exist and are not meaningless garbage.  So $x,y \in [0,1]$[*].
So we have $x+\sqrt 2 = y\in [0,1]$ but we also have $x\in [0,1]$.  Do you see the contradiction?
======
[*][If $w \not \in [0,1]$ then $w$ is not in the domain of $f$ and so talking about $f(w)$ is meaningless garbage.  We can't talk about $f(-1)$ or $f(2)$ any more than we can talk about $f(easter\ bunny)$ or $f(beef\ stew)$.]

Thank you sir for your help & support.

If $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational, and $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x+\sqrt2=y$. However, $\sqrt2>1$ so this tells us that
$$y=x+\sqrt2>0+1=1$$
which cannot be since $y\le1$. So, this case leads to a contradiction. (You anyway could not have gotten $x=y$ since one is rational and the other is not.)
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks, for the answer sir. You make it more clear! +1
